# Как в Exeption передать id из цикла, в случае ошибки?

Tags: oracle, plsql

При обновлении выскакивает ошибка ограничения. Нужно определить, на какой записи обновления ловит ошибку. Не могу передать эту запись в exeption блок, так как ругается:

> идентификатор 'CUR.CSRES_RESOLUTION_ID' должен быть объявлен

Понимаю, что цикл закрыт. Как в таком случае передать `CSRES_RESOLUTION_ID` в exeption?

```sql
DECLARE
    err_code VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN 
    FOR CUR IN (
        SELECT a.csres_resolution_id FROM CS_RESOLUTION A
        WHERE A.CSRES_RESOLUTION_NUMBER IN ('0356040','0356043','0356044')
    ) LOOP
        UPDATE CS_CASE B
        SET B.DCCST_CASE_STATUS_CODE='CLOSED BY PAYMENT'
        WHERE B.csres_resolution_id =CUR.csres_resolution_id;
    END LOOP;
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    err_code := SQLCODE;
    dbms_output.put_line(err_code||' '||CUR.csres_resolution_id );
END;
```

Comment: сделать внешнюю (по отношению к циклу) переменную (в том же declare) и на каждом шаге цикла перед update писать в нее значение

Comment: Mike, добрый день.  Не совсем понятно как записать именно ту запись на которой выскакивает ошибка. terr :=terr ||' '||cur.csres_resolution_id;

Comment: в цикле перед update просто `terr := cur.csres_resolution_id`. в ексцепшене используете terr вместо cur.csres_resolution_id

Comment: Отработало отлично.

Comment: Есть недостаток. В списке две записи возвращают констрайнт, а пишет процедура только 1 . Как сделать что бы все записи вывел с ошибкой ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С учетом комментария о необходимости вывода ошибок на все записи, обработку исключения надо перенести в сам цикл:

```
DECLARE
    err_code VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN 
    FOR CUR IN (SELECT a.csres_resolution_id FROM CS_RESOLUTION A
                 WHERE A.CSRES_RESOLUTION_NUMBER IN ('0356040','0356043','0356044')) LOOP
      BEGIN 
          UPDATE CS_CASE B
             SET B.DCCST_CASE_STATUS_CODE='CLOSED BY PAYMENT'
           WHERE B.csres_resolution_id =CUR.csres_resolution_id;
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
          err_code := SQLCODE;
          dbms_output.put_line(err_code||' '||CUR.csres_resolution_id );
      END;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

В случае необходимости отката всей транзакции при любой ошибке возможно стоит завести переменную - признак ошибки и выполнять commit только если она не установлена.

Answer (score 4):

Цикл для этой задачи вообще не нужен, воспользуйтесь `FORALL`.
С предикатом [SAVE EXCEPTIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-DAF46F06-EF3F-4B1A-A518-5238B80C69FA) все исключения сохранятся в массив `SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS`. Атрибут элемента этого массива `SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(iх).ERROR_INDEX` - индекс DML предложения, которое закончилось с исключением.

Пример для блока из вопроса:

```sql
declare
    type targetRow is record (rid rowid, csres_resolution_id number);
    type targetRows is table of targetRow;
    targets targetRows;
begin 
    select b.rowid, b.csres_resolution_id bulk collect into targets  
    from cs_resolution a
    join cs_case b on b.csres_resolution_id = a.csres_resolution_id
    where a.csres_resolution_number in ('0356040','0356043','0356044');

    declare
        dmlerrors exception;
        pragma exception_init (dmlerrors, -24381);
    begin 
        forall ix in indices of targets save exceptions
            update cs_case b set 
                b.dccst_case_status_code = 'CLOSED BY PAYMENT'
            where b.rowid = targets(ix).rid;
        dbms_output.put_line (sql%rowcount||' row(s) updated.');    

    exception when dmlerrors then
        for ix in 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count loop
            dbms_output.put_line (
                'Error id='||targets(sql%bulk_exceptions(ix).error_index).csres_resolution_id||
                ' '||sqlerrm||(-(sql%bulk_exceptions(ix).error_code)));
        end loop;
    end;
end;
/
```